# Android Volley StringRequest gives empty prams sometimes

Tags: android, android-volley

I have been trying to solve this for over a week, I have a volley string request that send feedbacks to php server and then save to database.

android code :

```
final Button sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String messageFinal = message.getText().toString();

        if(messageFinal.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(FeedbackActivity.this, "Message is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        String sendUrl = "https://example.com/feedback.php";
        StringRequest jsonRequestSend = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, sendUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("respond", response);
                try
                {
                    JSONObject respondObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if(respondObject.get("response").equals("true")){
                        Intent homepageIntent = new Intent(FeedbackActivity.this, GlobalListActivity.class);
                        FeedbackActivity.this.startActivity(homepageIntent);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", userEmail);
                params.put("message", messageFinal);
                return params;
            }
        };

        jsonRequestSend.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,-1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(FeedbackActivity.this);
        rQueue.add(jsonRequestSend);
    }
});
```

and in php I have this to send feedback to database :

```
require_once('dbConnect.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$now = new \DateTime('now');
$dateTime = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$status = "new";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `yc_contacts` (`Email`,`Message`,`Date` ,`Status` ) VALUES('$email', '$message' , '$dateTime' , '$status')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $res = "true";
} else {
    $res = "false";
}

$response = (object) [
    'response' => $res
];

echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I have tried this from 3 different devices and it works, but sometimes i get empty results in database no message and no email. can anyone help me here ? , what I am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

After doing further digging I now know that when I get in header something like this : `User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; SM-N960U Build/PPR1.180610.011)`
I get data correctly but when i get this kinda user agent :

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)
```

then I only get empty data, should this be solved in client or server side, and how can i solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can Prevent Empty Data insertion into database

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
        // insert into table
}
```

Or else you can check those post data in android side it's empty or not.

Comment: Thats not exactly my problem, the problem is that users send data but I get empty data.